# How to convert cell elements to columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Column1         Column2
String1         Element3, Element1, Element3, Element2
String2         None
String3         Element10
....
String5000     Element10, Element1
```

For each String in Column1 these are the possible options in Column2:

- There are no associated elements, in which case column 2 shows "None", or
- There can be up to 10 distinct elements associated. These can appear in any order, and be repeated any number of times (up to a limit of 25 elements for each string).

For me to be able to get a measure of the distribution of elements across strings, I would ideally need the following output, with individual elements as Column headers, with the count for each associated to each string.

```
Column1 Element1     Element2  Element3 ... Element10 None
String1    1              1      2              0       0
String2    0              0      0      ...     0       1
String3    0              0      0      ...     1       0
....
String5000 1              0     0       ...     1       0`
```

I'm new to R and have only managed to put each element in a separate column.

```
df <- read_delim("file.tsv", "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
df2 <-str_split_fixed(df$Column2, ",", n=25)
dfnew<- cbind(df, df2)
dfnew$Column1<- NULL`
```

The above gets me this:

```
Column1     1             2             3    ...    10 
String1     Element3     Element1    Element3     Element2
String2     None
String3     Element10
...
String5000  Element10    Element1`
```

But I'm stuck and have no clue as to what to do next. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We bring `Column2` in long format by separating comma-separated values into different rows, `count` each `Column2` value for `Column1` and `spread` the counts to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Column2, sep = "\\s*,\\s*") %>%
  count(Column1, Column2) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  spread(Column2, n, fill = 0, drop = FALSE)

#  Column1 Element1 Element10 Element2 Element3
#  <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 String1        1         0        1        2
#2 String2        0         0        0        0
#3 String3        0         1        0        0
```

I have assumed for empty values you have `NA` in `Column2`. If you have string like `"None"` replace it with `NA` first by doing

```
df$Column2[df$Column2 == "None"] <- NA
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Column1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("String1", 
"String2", "String3"), class = "factor"), Column2 = structure(c(2L, 
NA, 1L), .Label = c("Element10", "Element3, Element1, Element3, Element2"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```